# To select a unique value from a column having multiple values MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

Table Structure is like this
Table Name:Employee

```
**Employee_Id   APPRS_TY_CD**
540589                2
540589               UNK
1952938               2
1952938              UNK
2488178               1
2488178              UNK
3818934               1
3818934              UNK
5402944               1
```

If a Employee ID has APPRS_TY_CD as (UNK AND a value) then APPRS_TY_CD should be a value and not UNK. If APPRS_TY_CD is not UNK for an Employee ID then that value should be populated as it is.

My final output should look like this.

```
**Employee_Id   APPRS_TY_CD**
540589                2
1952938               2
2488178               1
3818934               1
5402944               1
```

I'm using MS Access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be fairly simple as numbers are considered "lower" than strings you can use an aggregate function, I've created an [SQL Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/681fe/1) (note this is Sql Server but the code should be the same as it's not using proprietary features). Given your data you could use the `MIN` function from SQL to get the `APPRS_TY_CD` for each user. Here is my suggested code:

```
SELECT 
    Employee_Id
    , MIN(APPRS_TY_CD) APPRS_TY_CD
FROM 
    Employee
GROUP BY 
    Employee_Id
```

The results returned are (you should be able toe execute the fiddle yourself to prove this):

```
EMPLOYEE_ID    APPRS_TY_CD
540589         2
1952938        2
2488178        1
3818934        1
5402944        1
```

Comment: Thanks @talegna it works!!.So this works based on the ASCII value is it?

Comment: It's my understanding that `MIN` (& `MAX`) order by magnitude e.g numerically or alphabetically. This can also be used for dates etc.